# I had a postdoc interview (UK based) last Monday and haven't heard back. Should I contact HR?

Tags: job-search

I had a postdoc interview for a job (social sciences) I am really interested in last Monday. I thought the interview went well and I was told I would hear back within the week. As of today I still have not heard back, and I was wondering if now is a good time to contact HR and ask for an update?

Would this be okay, or should I just keep waiting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Its normal they take a bit longer. Possibly you are the second option and they are waiting for the first to confirm/reject the position, for example.

I'd say wait 3~5 days more than what they told you, then send a polite email saying how much you enjoyed the interview and if there are any news. No one will take it badly, its part of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!